# Where is the stake amount stored in Proof-of-Stake?

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus, bitcoin, casper

So in the PoS consensus algorithm, the nodes can lock their coins and the node with the highest coins has the highest probability of getting the chance for validating coins.

I have two questions:

1) How does the process of staking coins take place? Like does the node who wants to stake their coins, send those coins to some address?

2) Who keeps track of how much is staked by whom? Is that number stored in the blockchain?

Thank You.